# Tomcat 8.0 cannot run a new application

Tags: tomcat, port

I have a web App running on tomcat web server 8.0
The web app is running on port 8080. I no longer want this app and i want a different app to run on the same port. But tomcat is not starting and throwing error `Port 8080 is already in use`. How do i stop the previous app completely?
When I used windows 7 i used to kill javaw process. Now in windows 10, javaw is not listed as a process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resolve your problem just try it :

1.Go to the bin directory of Tomcat and run shutdown.bat

2.You can use utility from the Beyond Logic website in below link for kill processes:

[utility from the Beyond Logic website](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/kill-processes-from-the-windows-command-line/)

Answer (score 1):

One Tomcat instance can run (and usually run) multiple applications, seems idea in question is wrong

Must deploy ("upload") WAR packaged application from manager panel, or put this file into folder for example `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps`

In typical configuration WAR is decompressed automatically and active in few second without Tomcat restart.